# User input stopping timer and task

Tags: batch-file, timer

Is it possible to have in a batch file a message saying "press any key to abort task" and have it on a timer? When the time runs out, it continues on with the task. If the user presses a key, the task doesn't run. If so, I could use this for a script I am working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If the user presses a key, the task shouldn't run

The nearest I can come up with is the following, which requires the user to press <kbd>Y</kbd>  or <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
choice /c:CY /n /m "Task will run in 30 seconds. Press Y to run now, or C to Cancel" /t:30 /d:Y
if errorlevel 2 (
  echo run task
  ) else (
  echo task cancelled
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Timeout is 30 seconds, modify to your requirements
- Replace `echo run task` with the command to run your task.
- Remove the `else (...)` if you don't need it.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) - Accept user input to a batch file. Choice allows single key-presses to be captured from the keyboard.